# Compilation Error CS0103 in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity

I'm working on a project with ASP.NET and SQL Server 2012, and when I try to load the project it says:

> Compilation Error CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the
>   current context

This is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<SegundoParcialP3.Models.Productos>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Precio)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in model) {
    <tr> 
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Precio)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
    <tr> 
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit") |@*, new { id=item.Id }*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details") |@*, new { id=item.Id }*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete") | @*, new { id=item.Id }*@
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
@foreach (var item in model) {
```

change it to:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
```

lowercase model is not anything, uppercase is a member of the ViewPage class.

As a side note, it would have been easier to find this if you hadn't used the word "model" virtually everywhere...  When you have these problems, start renaming things when you can.  That can help narrow it down.

Comment: I'll change the word "model" then and see how it goes... but in the meantime, when I change "var item in model" to "var item in Model" it says this error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @RenelisElizaRenelisAR - that's because your model is null.  You need to instantiate a model and pass it to your view or check if it's null before iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I created Views folder manually.
Fix: I created a Web.config file under Views folder and added the configuration details. Please see below.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```